# No interactive markers in rviz plugin MotionPlanning

Tags: moveit, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

ROS environment variables:

```
ROS_ROOT=/opt/ros/kinetic/share/ros
ROS_PACKAGE_PATH=/home/wang/imta_project/BetaGo/BetaGo_ws/src:/opt/ros/kinetic/share
ROS_MASTER_URI=http://localhost:11311
ROS_VERSION=1
ROSLISP_PACKAGE_DIRECTORIES=/home/wang/imta_project/BetaGo/BetaGo_ws/devel/share/common-lisp
ROS_DISTRO=kinetic
ROS_ETC_DIR=/opt/ros/kinetic/etc/ros
```

rviz:

```
[ INFO] [1583684440.312466155]: rviz version 1.12.17
[ INFO] [1583684440.312497891]: compiled against Qt version 5.5.1
[ INFO] [1583684440.312505512]: compiled against OGRE version 1.9.0 (Ghadamon)
```

We build a robot and use moveit to control the robot. The planning and execute in rviz plugin motionplanning works well, but the interactive marker disappeared as shown in the first image of this [page](https://github.com/TouchDeeper/BetaGo/tree/master/betago_manipulation)

The project packages is in [github](https://github.com/TouchDeeper/BetaGo). According to the README [here](https://github.com/TouchDeeper/BetaGo) and the [only Moveit mode](https://github.com/TouchDeeper/BetaGo/tree/master/betago_manipulation#only-moveit), you can reproduce the problem.

I check the xacro file of model by `check_urdf <(xacro --inorder ridgeback.urdf.xacro)` and the output is below:

```
    robot name is: ridgeback
---------- Successfully Parsed XML ---------------
root Link: base_link has 3 child(ren)
    child(1):  chassis_link
        child(1):  axle_link
            child(1):  front_rocker_link
                child(1):  front_left_wheel_link
                child(2):  front_right_wheel_link
            child(2):  rear_rocker_link
                child(1):  rear_left_wheel_link
                child(2):  rear_right_wheel_link
        child(2):  front_cover_link
        child(3):  front_lights_link
        child(4):  imu_link
        child(5):  left_side_cover_link
        child(6):  rear_cover_link
        child(7):  rear_lights_link
        child(8):  right_side_cover_link
        child(9):  top_link
    child(2):  camera_rgb_frame
        child(1):  camera_depth_frame
            child(1):  camera_depth_optical_frame
        child(2):  camera_link
        child(3):  camera_rgb_optical_frame
    child(3):  mid_mount
        child(1):  left_ur_arm_base_link
            child(1):  left_ur_arm_base
            child(2):  left_ur_arm_shoulder_link
                child(1):  left_ur_arm_upper_arm_link
                    child(1):  left_ur_arm_forearm_link
                        child(1):  left_ur_arm_wrist_1_link
                            child(1):  left_ur_arm_wrist_2_link
                                child(1):  left_ur_arm_wrist_3_link
                                    child(1):  left_ur_arm_ee_link
                                    child(2):  left_ur_arm_tool0
        child(2):  right_ur_arm_base_link
            child(1):  right_ur_arm_base
            child(2):  right_ur_arm_shoulder_link
                child(1):  right_ur_arm_upper_arm_link
                    child(1):  right_ur_arm_forearm_link
                        child(1):  right_ur_arm_wrist_1_link
                            child(1):  right_ur_arm_wrist_2_link
                                child(1):  right_ur_arm_wrist_3_link
                                    child(1):  right_ur_arm_ee_link
                                    child(2):  right_ur_arm_tool0
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/346185/no-interactive-markers-in-rviz-plugin-motionplanning/) by [TouchDeeper](https://answers.ros.org/users/39695/touchdeeper/) on ROS Answers with karma: 57 on 2020-03-08

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

From [betago_manipulation/betago_moveit_config/config/kinematics.yaml](https://github.com/TouchDeeper/BetaGo/blob/07525b91030ea3d42a57f8a2494dc07442c39a26/betago_manipulation/betago_moveit_config/config/kinematics.yaml) it would appear you have no kinematics solvers configured at all:

```
{}
```

The interactive marker you are most likely referring to only work for groups which have IK solvers configured.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2020-03-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [CodingCatMountain](https://answers.ros.org/users/79386/codingcatmountain/) on 2021-08-03**:
Sir，May I Ask A Question？THE version of my moveit setup Assistant is 2.0. Then the auto-generated kinematics.yaml is  "{}". I do choose the argues following the tutorial: http://docs.ros.org/en/melodic/api/moveit_tutorials/html/doc/setup_assistant/setup_assistant_tutorial.html